# Quicksort Algorithm with one function

Tags: java, quicksort

```
public static void sort(int[] a){
        if (a.length>1){
            int pivot=a[a.length-1];
            int left=0;
            int right=a.length-1;
            while(left<=right){
                while(a[left]<pivot)
                    left++;
                while(a[right]>pivot)
                    right--;
                if(left<=right){
                    int tmp=a[right];
                    a[right]=a[left];
                    a[left]=tmp;
                    left++;
                    right--;
                }
            }
            int[] tmp1=new int[right];
            for(int i=0;i<tmp1.length;i++)
                tmp1[i]=a[i];
            int[] tmp2=new int[a.length-right-1];
            for(int i=left;i<a.length;i++)
                tmp2[i-left]=a[i];
            sort(tmp1);
            sort(tmp2);
        }
    }
```

Im trying to write a quicksort algorithm with one function and it doesn't work. Any help is aprrecitated. Thanks

EDIT: I solved it thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: It doesn't sort it correctly. I've tried with multiple sizes and values of arrays and it sorts them wrong every time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that at the end you are not using the `tmp1` and `tmp2` to conform the new array `a`... Here is a way to do it without creating others arrays:

```
    public static void sort(int[] a, int left, int right){
        if (left < right){
            int pivot = a[right];
            int pos = left - 1;
            for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
                if (a[i] <= pivot)
                    Swap(a, ++pos, i);
            Swap(a, pos + 1, right);
            sort(a, left, pos);
            sort(a, pos + 1, right);
        }

    }

    public  static void Swap(int[] a, int i, int j){
        int temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
```

The first call of sort must be `sort(a, 0, a.length - 1)`

I hope this helps you

Comment: I have to implement it with one function and the function can only accept an array. I figured it out though, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort method seems extremely compared to most int sort methods. Here is a quick and easy one.

```
public static void sort(int[] intArray){
    int n = intArray.length;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){
            if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
                temp = intArray[j-1];
                intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                intArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a bubble sort. I don't see the point of the recursion. There a bunch of other types of sorts but for a short array length this is the easiest (IMO). Look up some other ones, its kinda cool what they do ([Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)).

To get to your question....
Like @RobinCurbelo said, you didn't use `temp1` and `temp2` correctly. Your idea is there but I think you were thinking too much into what you needed to do.